# Auto-generation of a Google doc based on google sheets selection + additional data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-docs

**Requirement**: Auto-generation and completion of a Google doc based on selections made by filtering options in Google sheets

**Step-by-step**:

1. There are x options listed in a spreadsheet.
   [image: all google sheets options]
2. I reduce them to the number I need via filtering.
   [image: filtered google sheet options]
3. I then have these options + the expanded details automatically added to a google doc template I've designed.
   [image: sample auto-completed Google doc with selected options + additional details]

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: I'm looking for recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

As an unexperienced programmer, it's very likely that the most convenient way to do something like this is by using Google Apps Script as it has services that help to extend Google Sheets and Google Docs among other Google apps. This service use JavaScript as programming language and it's possible to create and manage the script by using a web browser.

Experienced programmers that don't want to invest too much time on doing this might also find convenient to use Google Apps Script, but they might prefer to use the tools used for other projects might use CLASP or the Google Apps Script API.

Besides using Google Apps Script this could be done by using Google Docs API, Google Sheets API, Google Drive API and Google Cloud.